# Cannot open file /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier

Tags: c++, fopen

I have following function `isEthernetCableConnected()` which I am calling in a thread in continuous loop. After a long time I started to get log "Could not open /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier". How can it be possible? If it is possible then please give me some idea how to open the file every time.

```
ETH_FILE_CARRIER /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier

    int isEthernetCableConnected(){
    FILE *fp = fopen(ETH_FILE_CARRIER, "r");
    int result;
    if(fp == NULL) { 
        CLog::getInstance()->error("utility",__LINE__,__FILE__,"networked::isEthernetConnected, Could not open %s", ETH_FILE_CARRIER);
        return 0;
    }
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&result);
    fclose(fp);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You could use [`strerror`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strerror.html) to print out the reason that the `fopen` fails.

Comment: Consider logging `errno` value (and `strerror(errno)`) to see what error code `fopen` fails with. Could be just anything - for example, maybe you leak file descriptors somewhere and eventually you can't open new files.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link, it might help you
    http://wikistack.com/how-to-check-if-ethernet-cable-is-connected-linux

In this link, they are trying to open the file in different way. May be you can try that.